# How to execute image in table(interface) in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have successfully execute this code and i get my output.

```
If txt1.Text = "abc" Then
  txt2.Text = "11111"
End If

Dim sb As New StringBuilder
 For Each c as Char in txt2.Text
  sb.AppendFormat("<img src='{0}.jpg' />", c)
Next
  Literal1.Text = sb.ToString()
```

my output is such as like image below

[image]

I want to put this output inside a table and final look like image shown. How I'm going to address Literal1.Text to do that ?

Comment: [How to display image in text box in vb.net?][1] Forgot your own question?!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289556/how-to-execute-image-in-tableinterface-in-vb-net

Comment: just warp it all in a <table></table> with <tr></tr> and <td></td> element inside. Have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp